# adapter for recyclerview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

currently i am working on a android project. 
where i have two String[], now i want to display the data of bothe String[] on my activity.but with my code i am only able to display the data of one String[].
plz check my code.

file name:MyAdapter4.java

```
    public class MyAdapter4 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter4.MyViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;


    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public CardView cardview4;
        public EditText edit4;
        public TextView title4;
        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);


            cardview4=(CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view4);
            edit4=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.otherEdit);
            title4=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.otherTitle);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter4(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter4.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                      int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.other_file_layout, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        MyAdapter4.MyViewHolder vh = new MyAdapter4.MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter4.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title4.setText(mDataset[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

with this code i am only able to display Textview.... but editText is not showing data

and this is the code which i used to attach the adapter

```
public class FourFragment extends Fragment {
    public static String[] arrayOtherTitle, arrayOtherData;

    public FourFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_four, container, false);

        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view4);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        MyAdapter2 adapter = new MyAdapter2(arrayOtherTitle);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

The layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/card_view4"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/otherTitle"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/copy"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/otherEdit"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

As you can see, 
1)in my layout file, there are one textview and one edittext.
2)and in the class, FourFragment.java there are two String[] arrayOtherTitle, and arrayOtherData.
3)so, i want to display them on my activity.
where textview will contain data of arrayOtherTitle,
and editext will contain data of arrayOtherData.

but according to my code, currently i am only able to display data of arrayOtherTitle on textview.
and i am new in this topic,plz anyone help me to display the other arrayOtherData data on edittext.

please

Comment: You're sure that mDataset has values?

Comment: "but editText is not showing data", you sure about that? `holder.edit4.setText` seems to be called... Maybe also try to do `holder.title4.setText` in there?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve], please? How is `arrayOtherTitle`, which is just a `String[]`, going to be "two columns"?

Comment: @cricket_007 - Textview is already having static data set in xml

Comment: @nipun.birla They both have static text...

Comment: You need to create a Custom Data `Object` that holds 2 `Strings` - one for each column.  Then your dataset will change from `private String[] mDataset;` to `private List<Data> mDataset;` - pass in the 2 strings from the 2 columns in the database in a constructor `Data data = new Data(columnA, columnB)` add a new `Data` Object to a `List` (your data set) for each row and expose these through getters, that way your object is also immutable.

Comment: plz check my edited question. i this the new edited question is now understandable

Comment: @Mark Keen, can you please show me the example, how can i do this? please.

Comment: @nipun,@cricket_007- i want to change the data of edittext and textview on runtime

Comment: I'm not writing an answer as I can see other issues with your code, which I wouldn't be happy putting in my answer which would solve your immediate problem but not other problems - you have `public static String[] arrayOtherTitle, arrayOtherData;`.  Firstly class member variables should be unchanging variables i.e. you can reason exactly what they are at all times.  You are using them as your dataset(s) - what happens if you don't initialise them (presumably done from another `Fragment` or `Class`) you will pass to your adapter a null object, which will throw a `NullPointerException` ...